# save option is hidden in views

Tags: views, 7

[image]

Recently when i try to add fields in views save option has been hidden, I don't know how it happened, Is there any solution to overcome this ?

Comment: Did you clear all caches and check ?

Comment: Ok i will check and reply

Comment: I cleared cache but same issue persists

Comment: If you give some more information it would be helpful.If you have done any changes please mention those things.

Comment: I have been created some views and blocks but didn't made any changes in configuration..Recently i disabled some modules .. don't exact module but those are not related to views.

Comment: It can be issue in you css. Check inspecting the button.

Comment: Thanks @SumitMadan,I fixed it, Just added button class in css , Its worked

Comment: great dude.. ;)